# Does Dynamics AX Natively Mitigate Buffer Overflow?

Tags: axapta

Managed C# code is natively protected from Buffer Overflow attacks as it's compiled into CLR before being run and checked for any potential attacks.

Does Microsoft Dynamics AX, particular 4.0, have any similar mitigation technique?

If so, can you point me to a whitepaper outlining this, preferably from Microsoft?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .Net verifies the CIL code before execution (unless declared `unsafe`).

Dynamics AX does not when executing p-code. In AX 2012 all AX classes are also saved as CIL, which is executed under [certain circumstances](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg839855.aspx). This code is verified by .Net as usual.

That said, AX do runtime checks on all array references, string substrings etc. You will not  be able to make a program that crash the AX runtime (unless you know a weakness).

Also certain APIs deemed unsafe are secured by [Code Access Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190039.aspx).

Comment: That was my fear. Do you have any documentation to this effect?